# Shorten the Firebase dynamic link

Tags: android, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

Previously, I use the following dynamic link to launch a desired page in my app

```
http://jstock.co/a/news?code=1295.KL&symbol=PUBLIC+BANK+BHD
```

However, this has a shortcoming, for user who doesn't install my app. For user who doesn't install my app, this is what happen when he clicks on the link

1. Go to Google Play store
2. Install the app.
3. Launch the app. **Will go to the first page of the app, instead of the desired page specified in deep link.**

Later, I realize Firebase dynamic link can resolve my problem. If I use the following URL, everything works fine.

```
https://g7b6h.app.goo.gl/?link=http%3A%2F%2Fjstock.co%2Fa%2Fnews%3Fcode%3D1295.KL%26symbol%3DPUBLIC%2BBANK%2BBHD&apn=org.yccheok.jstock.gui
```

For 3rd step, instead of going to the first page of the app, user can now go straight to the desired page specified in deep link.

However, I feel the above link is too long. After reading https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/android/create, I try to shorten it using the following way

```
private void build() {
    Task<ShortDynamicLink> shortLinkTask = FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().createDynamicLink()
            .setLongLink(Uri.parse("https://g7b6h.app.goo.gl/?link=http%3A%2F%2Fjstock.co%2Fa%2Fnews%3Fcode%3D1295.KL%26symbol%3DPUBLIC%2BBANK%2BBHD&apn=org.yccheok.jstock.gui"))
            .buildShortDynamicLink()
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<ShortDynamicLink>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<ShortDynamicLink> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.i("CHEOK", "success");
                        // Short link created
                        Uri shortLink = task.getResult().getShortLink();
                        Uri flowchartLink = task.getResult().getPreviewLink();

                        Log.i("CHEOK", "shortLink = " + shortLink);
                        Log.i("CHEOK", "flowchartLink = " + flowchartLink);

                    } else {
                        Log.i("CHEOK", "error : " + task.getException().getMessage());
                        // Error
                        // ...
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

However, every-time, I will get `error : Bad Request`.

Any idea what step I had missed out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bad Request could well indicate an invalid API key - that is used to authorise the request. What I would do is:

1. Re-download google-services.json from the [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com) and overwrite the one in your project
2. Check that the API key parameter is filled for the entry for your package name under `/api_key/current_key` in the json file
3. Check that you have included the google-services plugin and called `apply` at the bottom of your app build.gradle

You can check against the steps in the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#manually_add_firebase

That should hopefully fix the API access.

While you are at it, you might want to check the debug version of your link: https://g7b6h.app.goo.gl/?link=http%3A%2F%2Fjstock.co%2Fa%2Fnews%3Fcode%3D1295.KL%26symbol%3DPUBLIC%2BBANK%2BBHD&apn=org.yccheok.jstock.gui&d=1 (&d=1 on the end). That shows a couple of warnings to resolve in the console.

Comment: Thanks. When I re-download `google-services.json`, it works. There's difference in API key. When I tested the generated `https://g7b6h.app.goo.gl/GkXlEGTokGA3Cr7r2`, it works as expected. However, the 2 warnings from flow chart confused me. It states `org.yccheok.jstock.gui` and `org.yccheok.demo` lack of SHA256. I had doubled check SHA256 in release and debug key, they matched with the one in firebase console. Also, I don't have any app with package `org.yccheok.demo` in firebase console. Hence, the warning message further confuse me. Should I just ignore the warnings?

Answer (score 3):

My guess would be that the URI in your `setLongLink` method does not need to be UTF-8 encoded. Firebase's example shows this:

```
Task<ShortDynamicLink> shortLinkTask = FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().createDynamicLink()
    .setLongLink(Uri.parse("https://abc123.app.goo.gl/?link=https://example.com/&apn=com.example.android&ibn=com.example.ios"))
    .buildShortDynamicLink()
```

Hopefully, that fixes your issue, but I never really know with Firebase.

My suggestion for dealing with this in a much simpler fashion would be to switch deep linking to [Branch](http://branch.io) (full disclosure I work there, but have previously developed with Firebase). It auto generates short links because the links actually store JSON-type objects under the hood instead of within the parameters. Just a thought :)

Answer (score 0):

With kotlin coroutines

```
private suspend fun getShortUrl(fullPath : String) : String? {
    return suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
        FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance()
            .shortLinkAsync(ShortDynamicLink.Suffix.UNGUESSABLE) {
                longLink = Uri.parse(fullPath)
                domainUriPrefix = BuildConfig.PATH_RECEIVE_HOST
            }
            .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
                val shortLink = result.shortLink
                continuation.resume(shortLink.toString())
            }.addOnFailureListener {
                Log.e(TAG, "--> getShortUrl ", it)

                continuation.resume(null)
            }
    }
```